# Load testing throws Server 502 error: Bad Gateway after 700 users. Gunicorn, Gevent, Nginx, Django

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, postgresql, django, gunicorn

I'm trying to reach 2000 concurrent users with my benchmarking tool. I'm using locust to simulate them.

My server has 24vCPUs, 128GB RAM, 25SSD.

I want to be able to serve 2000 concurrent users without errors but after only 700 users I run into trouble.

### Gunicorn

I installed gevent to be able to serve async but this didn't change anything on my load test (can gevent not be working?).
My systemd file is as follows:

**mysite-production.conf**

```
    [Unit]
    Description=mysite production daemon
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    User=www-data
    Group=www-data
    WorkingDirectory=/var/www/mysite/production/src
    ExecStart=/var/www/mysite/production/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class=gevent --worker-connections=1000  --workers=49 --bind unix:/var/www/mysite/production/sock/gunicorn --log-level DEBUG --log-file '/var/www/mysite/production/log/gunicorn.log' mysite.wsgi:application
    ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
    ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

According to my calculations: 49 x 1000 = 49000 requests per second that I could be serving.

Instead at about 700 users I get the following error in my locust failures tab:

```
# fails Method  Name    Type
1227    GET     //  HTTPError('500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://my.site.com//')
```

It basically says I have a internal server error.

when I open my gunicorn.log I see **Ignoring EPIPE**:

**gunicorn.log**

```
[2020-01-27 20:22:30 +0000] [13121] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
[2020-01-27 20:22:31 +0000] [13121] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
[2020-01-27 20:22:31 +0000] [13121] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
[2020-01-27 20:22:31 +0000] [13121] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
[2020-01-27 20:22:31 +0000] [13121] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
```

### Nginx

My nginx access.log shows some 499 and 500 errors:

**access.log**

```
185.159.126.246 - - [27/Jan/2020:19:22:25 +0000] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 200 30727 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
185.159.126.246 - - [27/Jan/2020:19:22:25 +0000] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
185.159.126.246 - - [27/Jan/2020:19:22:25 +0000] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
185.159.126.246 - - [27/Jan/2020:19:22:25 +0000] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 200 30727 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
185.159.126.246 - - [27/Jan/2020:19:22:25 +0000] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 500 2453 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
185.159.126.246 - - [27/Jan/2020:19:22:25 +0000] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 500 2453 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
185.159.126.246 - - [27/Jan/2020:19:22:25 +0000] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
185.159.126.246 - - [27/Jan/2020:19:22:25 +0000] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
```

the nginx error.log doesn't show anything, but in the previous test it showed **Resource temporary unavailable**:

**error.log**

```
2020/01/27 19:15:32 [error] 1514#1514: *57151 connect() to unix:/var/www/mysite/production/sock/gunicorn failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.159.126.246, server: my.site.com, request: "GET // HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/mysite/production/sock/gunicorn://", host: "my.site.com"
2020/01/27 19:15:32 [error] 1514#1514: *56133 connect() to unix:/var/www/mysite/production/sock/gunicorn failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.159.126.246, server: my.site.com, request: "GET // HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/mysite/production/sock/gunicorn://", host: "my.site.com"
```

Here is my nginx.conf:

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

events {
        worker_connections 4096;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
   }
```

and here is my server block:

**my.site.com (server-block)**

```
upstream mysite-production {
    server unix:/var/www/mysite/production/sock/gunicorn;
}
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name my.site.com;

    # set client body size to 100M #
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/mysite/production/sock/gunicorn;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/mysite/production/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        access_log off;
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/mysite/production/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

### Questions

Questions that come up when I look at all this:

Where does the 502 error come from? It does not show me enough information to understand what is happening... Are all my workers occupied after 700 users causing the errors?

Where does the 499 error come from?

Does it have anything to do with my postgresql database? if so how do I find out?

How can I know if gevent has worked or not? the results of the load tests with ab and locust haven't really changed.

what does **Ignoring EPIPE** mean and why is it happening?

I appreciate you taking the time to look at this. Thank you in advance for all your comments and answers!

**If you need more info please let me know and I will add it to my question.**

## EDIT:

Based on @ServerFaults comment I checked how much memory gets drained when the load test happens. apparently nothing really significant:

```
MemTotal:       132027088 kB
MemFree:        127013484 kB
MemAvailable:   126458072 kB
Buffers:           57788 kB
Cached:           401088 kB
```

After running `netstat -s` (I don't have the knowledge to understand what everything means):

```
Ip:
    Forwarding: 2
    6956023 total packets received
    8 with invalid addresses
    0 forwarded
    0 incoming packets discarded
    6953503 incoming packets delivered
    6722961 requests sent out
    20 outgoing packets dropped
Icmp:
    107 ICMP messages received
    0 input ICMP message failed
    ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 45
        echo requests: 62
    968 ICMP messages sent
    0 ICMP messages failed
    ICMP output histogram:
        destination unreachable: 906
        echo replies: 62
IcmpMsg:
        InType3: 45
        InType8: 62
        OutType0: 62
        OutType3: 906
Tcp:
    222160 active connection openings
    136492 passive connection openings
    78293 failed connection attempts
    161239 connection resets received
    2 connections established
    6245053 segments received
    6487229 segments sent out
    11978 segments retransmitted
    0 bad segments received
    185530 resets sent
Udp:
    667101 packets received
    41158 packets to unknown port received
    0 packet receive errors
    727164 packets sent
    0 receive buffer errors
    0 send buffer errors
UdpLite:
TcpExt:
    2939 SYN cookies sent
    28 SYN cookies received
    215 invalid SYN cookies received
    113 resets received for embryonic SYN_RECV sockets
    18751 TCP sockets finished time wait in fast timer
    175 packetes rejected in established connections because of timestamp
    61997 delayed acks sent
    54 delayed acks further delayed because of locked socket
    Quick ack mode was activated 3475 times
    2687504 packet headers predicted
    1171485 acknowledgments not containing data payload received
    2270054 predicted acknowledgments
    TCPSackRecovery: 921
    Detected reordering 22500 times using SACK
    Detected reordering 596 times using time stamp
    139 congestion windows fully recovered without slow start
    490 congestion windows partially recovered using Hoe heuristic
    TCPDSACKUndo: 14
    413 congestion windows recovered without slow start after partial ack
    TCPLostRetransmit: 47
    TCPSackFailures: 5
    7 timeouts in loss state
    2416 fast retransmits
    123 retransmits in slow start
    TCPTimeouts: 5279
    TCPLossProbes: 4284
    TCPLossProbeRecovery: 22
    TCPSackRecoveryFail: 1
    TCPDSACKOldSent: 3482
    TCPDSACKRecv: 1996
    TCPDSACKOfoRecv: 4
    52968 connections reset due to unexpected data
    54079 connections reset due to early user close
    51 connections aborted due to timeout
    TCPDSACKIgnoredOld: 25
    TCPDSACKIgnoredNoUndo: 822
    TCPSpuriousRTOs: 81
    TCPSackShifted: 4787
    TCPSackMerged: 5128
    TCPSackShiftFallback: 33199
    TCPReqQFullDoCookies: 2939
    TCPRcvCoalesce: 84434
    TCPOFOQueue: 26
    TCPChallengeACK: 3
    TCPAutoCorking: 7
    TCPFromZeroWindowAdv: 125
    TCPToZeroWindowAdv: 125
    TCPWantZeroWindowAdv: 1376
    TCPSynRetrans: 4695
    TCPOrigDataSent: 5023492
    TCPHystartTrainDetect: 2403
    TCPHystartTrainCwnd: 53596
    TCPHystartDelayDetect: 346
    TCPHystartDelayCwnd: 9883
    TCPACKSkippedSynRecv: 6
    TCPACKSkippedPAWS: 10
    TCPACKSkippedSeq: 15
    TCPWinProbe: 15
IpExt:
    InOctets: 6090026491
    OutOctets: 7098177391
    InNoECTPkts: 6966279
    InECT0Pkts: 11
    InCEPkts: 1
```

### Edit 2:

After creating a static html page without spawning Gunicorn, and it was able to easily serve 4000 users without any delays. After passing the worker_connections I received:

```
/loadtest/  ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='ll-my.site.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /loadtest/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x....>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))"))
```

From what I understand from this is that NGINX is not issue here.

### Edit 3:

I checked my postgresql logs and found out that it's full of this error:

```
FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Comment: What's available RAM look like when all 700 requests are active? The 502 might be Nginx telling you the back-end process can't spin up because it's out of RAM. 499 could be due to the client not being sent any data since the backend isn't answering. try `cat /proc/meminfo` while things are running. Also, do you have any swap configured?

Comment: @serverfault thank you for the comment! I've updated my answer with the results. It seems fine!

Comment: I'd have a look at TCP connections next. I'll sometimes run `tcpdump` to see what's going on a layer 2 and 3. `netstat -s` can be helpful or even `netstat -topnavelu`. Nginx tuning may be needed (https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/). Have you tried serving up a simple HTML page with Nginx instead of spinnning up Gunicorn on every request?

Comment: @serverfault I haven't tried serving a simple HTML page. I will do that now and get back to you. In the mean time I have run netstat -s and udpated my question with the results. I don't understand what they mean yet.

Comment: @serverfault I did test nginx on a static site and I got 4000 concurrent users easily. It only started failing when it exceeded worker_connections. I suppose this means it's not Nginx that causes the problem here correct?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that Gunicorn, or the application it's serving, is suspect at this point.  Maybe the next test could be a simple "Hello World" python script served over Gunicorn to see if things improve. After that, add a simple database `select` statement to see what happens (If you have a postgress/maria/mysql DB in the back). Those concurrency settings may need tuning as well. Check `/var/log/mysql/*` for errors if so.

Comment: The `netstat -r` TCP output shows a relatively large number of failed/reset packets. Was this from serving the static page?

Comment: @ServerFault I doubt that, I believe it was from my previous tests. When does it reset? per day? or never?

My postgresql logs show FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Comment: Maybe dropping the interface and bringing it up again would clear them, not sure. Reboot definitely would. Have you checked into that error message? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542727/remaining-connection-slots-are-reserved-for-non-replication-superuser-connection